# Adding Ads to List

Tags: android, listview, admob, adsense, ads

What would be the easiest way of including a fixed ad at the bottom of a list implemented like this one:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `addFooterView(View v)` method to add a static View to the end of the list.

Comment: Could I see an example of this in this instance?  I'm doing something wrong because I keep getting a force close..

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it with adsense, but I assume they are just some special subclass of `View`.

    `ListView lView = getListView();
    lView.addFooterView(AdSenseView);`


Also, if you could show your code/errors that would help.

Comment: With Adsense I'm just including the ad url in a WebView, but I'm not sure how to add that WebView to the footer or if you can even add a WebView to a footer?

Comment: I don't see any reason why a WebView wouldn't work with addFooterView. Just try it.

Comment: Why are you using a webivew at all? Google provides a custom view that serves ads on rotation.

Comment: AdMob is Google's Android Ad system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a custom listview, and on that listviewAdapter you can load the Ad.